# Database connection error while installing Informatica 9.6.1

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation, informatica

I am facing database connection error while installing Informatica 9.6.1. Please refer to the image below containing the error. I have searched the solution over the internet but no success.I ran below queries in SQL server [informatica error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmf0W.png) to find the values for each options.

To find the hostname:  `select HOST_NAME();`
To find the database service name: `SELECT @@SERVICENAME AS 'Service Name';`

I used the above as well as the '`SWATIMAHESHWARI`' as the database service name, nothing is working

Please help me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `localhost` in the hostname?

Comment: Hi @samik, yes I have written 'localhost' in place of ''swatimaheshwari-pc''. It did not work.

Comment: Check what `SELECT DB_NAME()` returns and try it as Database Service Name.

Comment: It is still not working @Samik . Please let me know if I need to install any drivers..

Comment: Please confirm the database name that you are using. Also, check that you are using the correct password for the SA account (and that the account is enabled on the SQL instance)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have TCP/IP enabled on SQL server. Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx